# SimpleForm PUTs to incorrect controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a SimpleForm set up like so:

```
= simple_form_for @profile, url: user_general_info_path, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  = f.input :name
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, class: 'btn-green'
```

It generates a form with this URL: `/user/general_info`

When I push a Submit button - here's what happens in console:

```
Started PUT "/user/general_info" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-23 10:27:30 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError - uninitialized constant User::GeneralInfosController:
```

Why would Rails look for User::GeneralInfosController (note - InfoS), when I specifically tell it to PUT into "/user/general_info"

Controller `User::GeneralInfoController` does exist.

Here is my routes file:

```
namespace :user do
  resource :general_info, only: [:update, :edit]
  root to: 'general_info#edit'
end
```

Comment: I assume you mean 'Controller `User::GeneralInfosController` does exist.' (note plural infos)

Answer (score 0):

Rails expects controller names to be pluralalized versions of the resource - even when the resource is singular. In this particular case it's particularly annoying because "GeneralInfos" makes no sense. Here are some options:

- Pluralize the controller. Sure it's ugly been then everything just works.
- Add an inflection so Rails knows "Info" is not a pluralizable word.
- pass the `controller: :general_info` option to your rute declaration. Note that the fact that this controller is namespaced might change what the exact value needs to be here.